# Can Thunderbird open folders of new emails into a new tab?

Tags: thunderbird

I'm moving from Eudora to Thunderbird... and I miss this feature: when new emails arrive, there are some rules that move them into a specific folder.

Is it possible, when it happens, to Thunderbird opens that folder inside a new tab?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can move message to specific folders with message filters.  You can find the configuration for these in the Tools menu.

I don't believe you can get the folder opened in a tab, but the folder will be highlighted in the folder panel.

Comment: Yes... Thunderbird inherits all the Eudora filters... but it misses my favourite feature: open folders in new tab after a new message incoming (due to message filtering)